# Ubuntu 22.04 wont unlock even with right password

Tags: 22.04, xorg

Ubuntu 22.04 wont unlock even with right password.
All I see is this and won't reset the textbox. I am using **Xorg** .

[image: wont unlock]

Comment: Open a virtual terminal with `ctrl + alt + f3`. Check whether you can login to the terminal with your username and password. If you can login, then the login screen (GDM) has some issue, which we will try to debug. To get out of the virtual terminal, press either `ctrl + alt + f1` or `ctrl + alt + f7`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I was logged into virtual terminal but still did this command and it worked. Command ran: `sudo su - someusername` . What about the gdm ?

Comment: It just confirms that the computer still recognizes the password. Let's wait for someone with more experience to answer how to fix it in GDM

Comment: I'm having the same problem, usually I just go to a terminal (ctrl-alt-f3) wait some seconds and go back to gdm (ctrl-alt-f2) and it unlocks. I'm still trying to figure out how to solve this permanently. BTW, I'm using Wayland, so it seems unrelated to the display server.